# Ngix com multiplos projetos angular

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

Olá, estou começando agora a usar o NGINX e de cara já tive um problema!

Eu estou utilizando um servidor ubundo para rodar 3 frontends angular, e então estou utilizando o NGINX para fazer o proxy reserso nesses projetos

A configurção que estou fazendo é a seguinte!

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name dominio.com.br www.dominio.com.br;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Accounts Portal
    location / {
            alias /fover-repository/accounts-portal/dist/BookingAccountsPortal/;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

}

Desse jeito se eu acesso o link diretamente dessa forma: 'www.dominio.com.br', funciona muito bem!

Porém o que eu desejo é acessar esse projeto com a seguinte rota: 'www.dominio.com.br/accounts'.

Quando eu coloco no location da seguinte maneira:

```
location /accounts/ {
        alias /fover-repository/accounts-portal/dist/BookingAccountsPortal/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Eu recebo 404 Not Found.

Como eu posso resolver isso?

Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema! Eu resolvi o meu problema removendo do arquivo index.html do projeto angular, a seguinte tag!

Como estava:

```
<base href="/">
```

Como ficou:

```
<base href="">
```

Com isso, funcionou perfeitamente